Prove simply-connected space forms satisfy SAS congruence axiom
We restate Hilbert's 6th axiom of congruence in the language of differential geometry:

On a complete Riemannian manifold $M$, given geodesic triangles $[pqr]$ and $[p'q'r']$ with $\operatorname{dist}(p,q)=\operatorname{dist}(p',q')$, $\operatorname{dist}(p,r)=\operatorname{dist}(p',r')$ and $\measuredangle rpq=\measuredangle r'p'q'$, then $\measuredangle pqr=\measuredangle p'q'r'$ and $\measuredangle qrp=\measuredangle q'r'p'$, where $\measuredangle xyz$ denotes the angle of initial vectors of geodesics adjoining $x,y$ and $y,z$.

This proposition is also known as SAS congruence axiom in elementary geometry.
I want to prove that every simply-connected space form (i.e., constant sectional curvature complete Riemannian manifold) satisfies SAS axiom, so that every simply-connected space form will provide a model of so-called absolute geometry (I don't care other axioms).
One direct but complicated approach I came up is: we only need to discuss space forms with sectional curvature $0,-1,1$, and we can calculate the geodesics and angles in model spaces (Euclidean space, Poincaré upper half plane, unit sphere) using analytic geometry.
However, I want an simpler proof using the intrinsic nature of constant sectional curvature spaces, such as simply-connected space forms are unique up to an isometry.
Any help will be appreciated.
Edit: We explain what does triangle mean.
A triangle is a figure consists of three points adjoined by minimal geodesics, and should not be colinear.

It depends on how much you know about geometry of spaceforms. For instance, do you know transitivity properties of the isometry group? Uniqueness of geodesics?

@MoisheKohan I know the two properties you mentioned. I can give a simple proof using these two properties, but I was stuck by some degenerate situation yesterday, so I posted this question. You can check my own answer posted below.

I had an answer after discussing with my supervisor and my schoolmates.
The main difficult (and the reason I post the question) is the geodesic triangle on sphere.
The proof assumes the knowledge of transitivity of isometry group on space forms and uniqueness of geodesics.
For general situation, let normal geodesics $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3$ adjoin $p\to q,p\to r$ and $r\to q$ respectively, where the arrow indicates direction.
Let orthonormal frame $\{e_i\}$ at $p$ satisfy $e_1=\dot{\gamma}_1(0)$, $e_2$ in the plane spanned by $\dot{\gamma}_1(0)$ and $\dot{\gamma_2}(0)$ making $\dot{\gamma_2}(0)$ lie between $e_1$ and $e_2$, and define $\gamma_i'$ $(i=1,2,3)$ and orthonormal frame $\{e_i'\}$ mutatis mutandis.
Let $\varphi$ be an isometry that takes $p$ to $p'$ and $\{e_i\}$ to $\{e_i'\}$.
Then $d\varphi|_p(\dot{\gamma}_1(0))=\dot{\gamma}_1'(0)$, $d\varphi|_p(\dot{\gamma}_2(0))=\dot{\gamma}_2'(0)$, by the uniqueness of geodesics, $\varphi(\gamma_1)=\gamma_1',\varphi(\gamma_2)=\gamma_2'$.
Moreoever, since $\operatorname{dist}(p,q)=\operatorname{dist}(p',q')$, $\operatorname{dist}(p,r)=\operatorname{dist}(p',r')$, we have $\varphi(q)=q',\varphi(r)=r'$, and $d\varphi|_r(\dot{\gamma}_2(s_2))=\dot{\gamma}_2'(s_2)$, where $s_2=\operatorname{dist}(p,r)$.
Now we discuss:

$q',r'$ are adjoined by unique minimal geodesic, then since isometry takes minimal geodesic to minimal geodesic, $\varphi(\gamma_3)=\gamma_3'$. Hence
$$\measuredangle qrp=\langle-\dot{\gamma}_2(s_2),\dot{\gamma}_3(0)\rangle=\langle-d\varphi|_r(\dot{\gamma}_2(s_2)),d\varphi|_r(\dot{\gamma}_3(0))\rangle=\langle-\dot{\gamma}_2'(s_2),\dot{\gamma}_3'(0)\rangle=\measuredangle q'r'p'$$
There are more than one minimal geodesics adjoining $q',r'$.
This can only happen when $M$ is a sphere and $q',r'$ are antipodal points.
In this situation, $p'$ lies on another geodesic adjoining $q',r'$, $[p'q'r']$ degenerates to a bigon.

Above discuss gives a proof to the question.
